# Symfony JSON auth setup - Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "user" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to Symfony and I'm trying to setup a REST API with a JSON web token authentication system.
When I'm running the server and I try to call the login route, I'm getting the following error, with a 500 Server Error response:

[SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "user" does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWoLR.png)

I'm using a docker container to run the DB, here is the error in it:

```
STATEMENT:  SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4 FROM "user" t0 WHERE t0.email = $1 LIMIT 1

ERROR:  relation "user" does not exist at character 96
```

But I can access my database using DBeaver and execute the statement without any problem.

I'm using the following security.yml configuration (default values as much as possible):

```yaml
security:
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: "auto"
  providers:
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      json_login:
        check_path: api_login
        username_path: email
        password_path: password


  access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
  security:
    password_hashers:
   
      Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
        algorithm: auto
        cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
        time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
        memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

I have followed the official doc about [Security setup](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) and JSON Login. Here are my User and ApiLoginController:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
   // ... Code left untouched here ...
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ApiLoginController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/api/login', name: 'api_login')]
    public function index(): JsonResponse
    {
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Welcome to your new controller!',
            'path' => 'src/Controller/ApiLoginController.php',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have read about the "user" (with quotes) table name can be a problem with Postgres, but the issue is still here even using another name.

More infos:

- Windows 10 or Linux Manjaro (tested on both)
- Symfony version - 6.0
- Doctrine Bundle version - 2.7
- PHP version - 8.1.8
- Docker image - postgres:13-alpine

Reproductible repo: https://github.com/Clm-Roig/symfony6-setup-issue

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you not to implement your own implementation for the use of jwts but to use for example an already existing and already established implementation.

The contribution of the Symfony documentation covers only the part of an authentication, but not the generation of the actual JWT. Especially the validation of the JWT is mandatory if you want to use the JWT for stateless authentication.

It doesn't solve your actual problem for now, but I strongly recommend you to think about using an appropriate bundle that generates the JWTs and takes care of the authentication.

Maybe this is a good bundle: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was planning to do it yes ! I'm discovering Symfony right now but I have a strong background in JS web frameworks, including authentication process :) 

I will try it in case it solves my problem, who knows...

Comment: Ok it worked! I don't know if it's really a solution to my initial answer but knowing that I had to install something to manage the JWT, it's ok for me. 
Thank you again!